# Повторный запуск JVM средствами JNI

Tags: jni, java, c++, jvm

Суть проблемы: с помощью jni я создаю окружение и джава машину, которая работает с этим окружением и с моим джава классом, который я вызываю уже из С++

для того что бы создать джава машину используется функция CreateJavaVM (&jvm, (void**)&env, &args)

делаю все что нужно и вызываю
DestroyJavaVM();

все работает, но когда пытаюсь запустить новую джава машину для других действий CreateJavaVM возвращает -1

по отдельности блоки типа

CreateJavaVM()
делаем что-то
DestroyJavaVM()

работают, но по очереди нет. в комьюнити оракла пишут

> The support for DestroyJavaVM was not complete in 1.1. Only the main thread may call DestroyJavaVM. In the Java 2 SDK, any thread, whether attached or not, can call this function. If the current thread is attached, the VM waits until the current thread is the only user-level Java thread. If the current thread is not attached, the VM attaches the current thread and then waits until the current thread is the only user-level thread. The Java 2 SDK still does not support VM unloading, however. DestroyJavaVM always returns an error code.

но я не могу сделать из этого выводов.

Comment: -- "зачем вообще выгружать? Пользуйтесь всегда одним и тем же экземпляром."

ну а если мне нужно изменить набор java классов с которыми я буду работать?

Comment: VladD

Дело в том что из приложения на с++ мы загружаем в джава окружение некоторые jar файлы (которые являются драйвером для управления некой базой)
Есть написанный на с++ интерфейс, который является оболочкой. 
и есть юнит тест в котором мы загружаем только тестовый джава класс.
.
как в запущенном Java-приложении подгрузить нужное окружение в таком случае?

Comment: @haku, почитал все и окончательно запутался.

Так в каком порядке и что у Вас все-таки происходит (желательно в терминах процессов)?

Как конкретно из C++ Вы загружаете .jar в *джава окружение*? (кстати, что это зверь такой?)

И еще -- ОС какая? (просто решение может оказаться системозависимым).

Comment: @avp, ОС Win 7
в переменную JavaVMInitArgs args; добавляю пути до *.jar или *.class
args.nOptions++;
classPathStream << _T( "-Djava.class.path=.;");
// из набора добавляем пути
for(auto it = m_classPaths.begin(); it != m_classPaths.end(); it++)
      {
         classPathStream << *it << _T( ";" );
      }
strcpy( options[args.nOptions - 1].optionString, classPathStream.str().c_str());
args.options = options;
// создание машины
int ret = createJavaVMPtr(&m_jvm, (void**)&m_env, &args);
окружение это m_env. после работы вызываю:
m_jvm->DestroyJavaVM()
PS не знаю как здесь отформатировать текст

Comment: @haku, если правильно понял, то код (который Вы не смогли отформатировать) это jni и Вы хотите добавить компоненты в classPath этой же JVM? 

А что за С++ приложение, о котором Вы пишете в комментарии для @VladD, и как оно взаимодействует c этим кодом (этой JVM)?

Comment: @avp

да это jni. Я хочу остановить jvm, создать аргумент для запуска с другими компонентами, и вновь запустить. Либо если это возможно поменять компоненты не останавливая jvm.

на C++ написаны классы дублирующие классы на java и из их методов я с помощью env (environment) вызываю соответствующие методы из j-классов

пример:

Env()->CallStaticObjectMethod(classname, methodID)

Comment: @haku, если Вы хоттите перезапустить "с нуля", то чем `execvpe()` (или какой-нибудь его виндовый аналог) Вас не устраивает?

Если что-то надо останавливать "graceful", то запустите новый вариант в новом процессе, возможно с небольшой задержкой, а текущий экземпляр JVM завершите.

Тут все зависит от внутренней кухни Вашего приложения, в которой мы не разбираемся.

Comment: @haku: А в чём проблема? Делайте так же, как делали раньше.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте не так.

1. Напишите нативный wrapper для своей программы (это может быть простой shell/bat-файл). который будет запускать Java-приложение в бесконечном цикле.
2. Придумайте критерий выхода из цикла (например, наличие или отсутствие некоторого файла).
3. Если Java-приложeние хочет сделать рестарт VM, пусть оно выставит флаг продолжения цикла для wrapper'а и завершится.
4. Если Java-приложeние хочет закончить работу, пусть сбросит флаг продолжения цикла для wrapper'а (и завершится).

Comment: > А в чём проблема? Делайте так же, как делали раньше.
суть как раз в том что не работает как раньше. один раз работает второй раз нет. 

совет с потоками тоже не подойдет, ибо такая ошибка возникает и в разных потоках, люди всяко пытались запустить повторно jvm возвращает -1

> если Вы хоттите перезапустить "с нуля", то чем execvpe() (или какой-нибудь его виндовый аналог) Вас не устраивает?

@avp просто не в курсе как через execvpe() установить нужное мне окружение. в jni все делается в одном контексте. к тому же работать должно под любой системой, поэтому пользуемся jni

Comment: @haku, читайте `man execvpe` (это POSIX).

А под любой системой одинаково только hello world работает.

Answer (score 0):

Раз выгрузка VM до сих пор не реализована, то выгрузить не удастся. Значит не надо и пытаться. Тем более что она вам опять понадобится - зачем вообще выгружать? Пользуйтесь всегда одним и тем же экземпляром.